# Golang cache result from handler net/http

Tags: go

Can't get result from cache. Work only requests to base. I need optimise app for many requests. This my first app with golang, be indulgent pls. How get cached result?

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/ip2location/ip2proxy-go"
    "github.com/patrickmn/go-cache"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
func HelloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := cache.New(5*time.Minute, 10*time.Minute)
    ip := r.URL.Query().Get("ip")
    x, found := c.Get(ip)
    if found {
        if x != "0" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "isProxy Cache")
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "notProxy Cache")
        }

    } else {
        db, err := ip2proxy.OpenDB("./IP2PROXY-IP-PROXYTYPE-COUNTRY.BIN")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        all, err := db.GetAll(ip)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
            return
        }
        isProxy := all["isProxy"]
        c.Set(ip, isProxy, cache.DefaultExpiration)
        if isProxy != "0" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "isProxy ")
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "notProxy ")
        }
        db.Close()
    }
}
```

This: all["isProxy"] return 0, 1, -1 values

Comment: can you format the code using `gofmt`?

Comment: The handler will never get a value from the cache because the handler creates a cache on every request.  Create the cache once outside of the handler

Comment: I don't understand how I can do this outside for query arg

Comment: The call `cache.New(5*time.Minute, 10*time.Minute)` does not use query arguments.   Replace local variable `c` with package-level variable `c` declared like this `var c = cache.New(5*time.Minute, 10*time.Minute)`.  The code in the question creates a discards a cache on every request, thus rendering the cache useless.

Comment: It is work, thank you <3!

Answer (score 2):

Make a global variable and store the cache there. Example:

```
var globalCache *cache.Cache

func main() {
    globalCache = cache.New(5*time.Minute, 10*time.Minute)

    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func HelloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // use globalCache
}
```

Update: atomic is not needed since cache.Cache makes locks internally. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use `atomic`? I would expect the global to be set at startup (in `main()`) and not changed after that. Races are possible when reading/writing to the cache but this should be handled within [`go-cache`](https://github.com/patrickmn/go-cache) (the docs say its thread-safe).

Comment: Are you about https://github.com/uber-go/atomic?

Comment: @SukinSun I believe the answer is using the standard library [`sync/atomic`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic). However I believe this is unnecessary (just define the global as `var globalCache cache.Cache`).